# Fourier transform for $xe^{-\pi y/2}$ and $\delta'(x)e^{-y^2/2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, generating-functions

We regarded $xe^{-\pi y^2/2}$ and $\delta'(x)e^{-y^2/2}$ as distributions on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then find the Fourier transform of them.

My attempt

$<F[xe^{-\pi y^2/2}],\phi>=<xe^{-\pi y^2/2},F[\phi]>$

$=-<e^{-\pi y^2/2},F[\partial_1\phi]>$

$=<F[e^{-\pi y^2/2}],\partial_1\phi>$

Then the problem is to figure out the Fourier transform of $e^{-\pi y^2/2}$.

Comment: It depends on your convention, but the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian, this is well known and is usually one of the first thing you learn  ... did you try google?

Comment: I know the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian, but it is in one dimensional, and what I asked is in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: No, in any dimension. A gaussian factorizes $e^{-x_1^2-x_2^2} = e^{-x_1^2} e^{-x_2^2}$ and so does the Fourier transform by Fubini theorem